# Redirect back to specific URL once payment is made

Tags: paypal

I've set up my PayPal button and I can make payments with it, so it does work.

I've set up redirecting and supplied the URLs to which I want PayPal to redirect (whether in case of cancelled or completed payments):

[image]

I realize that in the screenshot here, there's a / missing on the checkout path, but that's only because I "censored" the links after testing.

Is there anything more I need to do in order to make this redirect? All it's doing currently is spewing out the Thank You screen, which is great, but it's not what I need.

Can anyone suggest why it's not redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your button (or rather form)  have a return variable??

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

> return  -Optional - The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser
>   after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your
>   site that displays a "Thank you for your payment" page.  Default –
>   PayPal redirects the browser to a PayPal webpage.

edit: try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/thanks.html"/>
```

[Paypal - redirect after payment to my own page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178686/paypal-redirect-after-payment-to-my-own-page)

Comment: Yes I've added it and I've enabled Auto Return on the seller account as well, still all I end up seeing is the "Thanks for your order" screen :(

Answer (score 0):

on the checkout page, look for the 'cancel_return' hidden form element:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="" />
```

set the value of the cancel_return form element to the URL you wish to return to:

```
     <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="http://royaltytech.in" />
```